# unable to boot to windows 8.1 after installing Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 today. But after completion of installation I'm not getting that dual boot screen. I mean its directly getting booted up to Ubuntu. I cant boot to Windows 8.1 What to do?? Please reply asap

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming to the conclusion that most of the time when that very question is asked on this site, that the person doing the installation accidentally replaced Windows with Ubuntu instead of choosing "side by side" as the installation option.  Please open your [disk utility](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/) and see how many partitions you have on your boot hard drive.